# Hadoop Log File Analysis from 2 separate machines

Tags: hadoop

I am a fresher to Hadoop. I have to find the trend of symbols traded among users.

I have 2 machines b040n10 and b040n11. The files in the machine are as mentioned below:

```
b040n10:/u/ssekar>ls -lrt
-rw-r--r--   1 root root      482342353 Feb  8  2014 A.log
-rw-r--r--   1 root root      481231231 Feb  8  2014 B.log

b040n11:/u/ssekar>ls -lrt 
-rw-r--r--   1 root root      412312312 Feb  8  2014 C.log
-rw-r--r--   1 root root      412356315 Feb  8  2014 D.log
```

There is a field called "***symbol_name***" on all these logs (example below).

```
IP=145.45.34.2;***symbol_name=ABC;***timestamp=12:13:05
IP=145.45.34.2;***symbol_name=XYZ;***timestamp=12:13:56
IP=145.45.34.2;***symbol_name=ABC;***timestamp=12:14:56
```

I have Hadoop running on my Laptop and I have 2 machines connected to my Laptop (can be used as Datanodes).
My task now is to get the list of ***symbol_name*** and the Symbol count.
As mentioned below:
**ABC - 2 
XYZ - 1**

Should I now:
1. copy all the files (A.log,B.log,C.log,D.log) from b040n10 and b040n11 to my Laptop, 
2. Issue a copyFromLocal command to HDFS system and analyze the data?

or is there a better way to findout the symbol_name and count without copying these files to my laptop?

The question is a basic one, but I am new to Hadoop, please help me to understand and use Hadoop to better. Please let me know if more information on the question is need.

Thanks

Comment: I would encourage you to read at least the first 4 chapters from Hadoop Definitive Guide before you try and solve this problem, if you do not enjoy reading look for some videos about hadoop on youtube or the like.

Answer (score 0):

Copying the files from Hadoop to your local laptop defies the entire purpose of Hadoop which is to move the processing to the data *not* the other way. Because when you really have "BigData", you won't be able to move the data around to process it locally.

Your problem is a typical case of Map/Reduce, all what you need is a job that counts the occurrence of each symbol. Just search for Map/Reduce [WordCount example](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.0.4/mapred_tutorial.html) and adapt it to your case

Comment: Thanks for the update. My major doubt is must all my data that I have on Server b040n10 and Server b040n11 be on my Laptop to use Hadoop over the data? Please help me in understanding how the huge data that I have on my servers be analyzed using Hadoop (with the datanodes that I have).

Comment: You simply submit a map/reduce job from your laptop to run against Haddop cluster. The main idea is that data is processed locally on each node and then results are combined after the reduce phase.

Comment: Thanks again for the reply. Please bear with me until my basic doubts are cleared.
Another question is the servers I mentioned in my question, Server b040n10 and Server b040n11 do not have hadoop installed in them. They contain only the log files (~250 TB each). Please explain as to how I must handle this situation and use Hadoop that is installed only on my laptop?